# overlapping a task after await foreach() starts

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, grpc

Here's my scenario.  In an IHostedService I need to subscribe to a GRPC channel and process messages using await foreach().

```
    var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");
    var client = new Messenger.MessengerClient(channel);

    var messages= client.SubscribeToMessages();

    await foreach (var message in messages.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())
    {
        // do something with message
    }
```

Since I'm subscribing to a stream there is a chance that I have missed messages that the server sent prior to my client subscribing.  The MessengerClient has a method where I can get a snapshot of all messages for the current day:

```
  var snapshotMessages = client.GetTodaysMessages();
```

I'd like to call the client.GetTodaysMessages() after subscribing to the stream that way there is an overlap and I am guaranteed to get everything.

I was thinking about starting a timer right before my await foreach(...) and calling client.GetTodaysMessages() in the timer's callback. What do you think of this approach?

One requirement is that if I get disconnected from the GRPC stream I need to resubscribe and call the client.GetTodaysMessages() again.

I'm open for suggestions that you may have

Comment: Why call `GetTodaysMessages` *after* starting the loop? Or even in the same method? You could get the current messages and *then* start the loop. An even better idea would be to extract the processing code into eg an ActionBlock or behind a Channel and have the loop post messages to it. This way you could retrieve the current messages and post them to the consumer, then start retrieving the subscriptions and posting them as well. The consumer code would work the same

Comment: You could even use a timer to pull the current messages and post them to the consumer, provided the consumer rejects duplicates. All this depends on pulling the processing code out of the loop

Comment: The reason to make the request to getTodaysMessages after subscribing to the stream is that theoretically in the time between making the call to getTodaysMessages and subscribing to the stream there could be a burst of new  messages sent by the stream provider that we miss

Comment: And the work is being sent to an action block for processing.  It’s just not illustrated here

Comment: If the action block deduplicates messages you can call `getTodaysMessages()` on a timer and post them to the block. The block will reject the messages it's already seen. If the messages have a sequence number you could even detect missing messages and trigger a task that requests the missing messages

Comment: The missing code and more importantly, the protocol/conversation logic is important. Does the message order matter? How much latency can you afford? If order matters, you may need to cache out of order messages. A Dataflow block preserves order, so the batch of messages you post will be processed after any pending subscription messages. In both cases you could use a separate block to deduplicate and reorder the incoming messages before forwarding them to the worker block

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a document called [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) which may help you here.

Essentially, instead of calling `await`, you can instead assign your call to a `Task`, which will run while you are able to perform other actions. You can then wait for the `Task` to complete once you are ready. `Task`s have a `Result` property as well which contains the result from your awaited code.

There is a really helpful way to await multiple tasks by calling `Task.WhenAny()` on an array of tasks you are waiting on. Here is a bit of code from Microsoft (from the Asynchronous programming guide I linked above) where they are able to create several breakfast related tasks, and then `await` them all:

```cs
var breakfastTasks = new List<Task> { eggsTask, baconTask, toastTask };
while (breakfastTasks.Count > 0)
{
    Task finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(breakfastTasks);
    if (finishedTask == eggsTask)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Eggs are ready");
    }
    else if (finishedTask == baconTask)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bacon is ready");
    }
    else if (finishedTask == toastTask)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Toast is ready");
    }
    breakfastTasks.Remove(finishedTask);
}
```

You could try making your foreach a `Task` like (This was written off the cuff, I didn't try to compile this, but it may help you):

```cs
var task = messages.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync();

// do other work here, while the task runs
var snapshotMessages = client.GetTodaysMessages();

// and then deal with the result of the message stream

await task;

foreach(var message in task.Result){ 

  // process message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XY problem.

The solution to your problem is to not have your problem.

"Since I'm subscribing to a stream there is a chance that I have missed messages".

***This is a FEATURE of gRPC.***

Choose a technology where "Since I am using X, I have no chance of missing messages". You want to use a Message Queue instead of the Observable pattern. Look at

- MSMQ
- Rabbit MQ
- MQTT
- MassTransit
- Redis
- Tibco
- SimpleMQ
- etc

A message broker would solve your problem with zero code.

Comment: Unfortunately the producer only sends messages via grpc.  I do agree with you that grpc is not the correct mechanism here.

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking you'd do something like this:

```cs
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");
var client = new Messenger.MessengerClient(channel);

var messages = client.SubscribeToMessages();

// Get the stream going so that you don't miss any
var messagesEnumerableTask = messages.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync();

// Get today's messages
var snapshotMessages = await client.GetTodaysMessages(); // I'm asuming this is actually awaitable?

// Process today's messages
foreach (var message in snapshotMessages)
{
    if (!IsProcessed(message))
    {
        Process(message);
    } 
}

// Process the stream
await foreach (var message in messagesEnumerableTask)
{
    if (!IsProcessed(message))
    {
        Process(message);
    }
}
```

I imagine you'll have some kind of way of determining if a message has already been seen (e.g. a method called `IsProcessed(message)`).

Comment: Yes I can tell if a message has been processed.  My issue is making the snapshot messages execute after reading from the steam starts

Comment: @jsct01 doesn't my answer solve that?

Comment: Worst case scenario you could read the first item from the stream then get all messages for the day and then loop the rest of the stream.